# SASL LDAP authentication failure

Tags: authentication, ldap, sasl

Trying to use `SASL` AND `LDAP` to authenticate user in `RedHat Linux`. So far I've setup the `saslauthd` service and its up and running. My `/etc/saslauthd.conf` looks like follows:

```
ldap_servers: ldaps://test.ldap.server:1234
ldap_use_sasl: yes
ldap_mech: DIGEST-MD5
ldap_auth_method: fastbind
ldap_search_base: Ou=PeopleAuthSrch,DC=abc,DC=com
```

My `/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf` looks like the following:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

Now when I try to test the authentication with following command:

`testsaslauthd -u username -p password -f /var/run/saslauthd/mux`

I get `0: NO "authentication failed"`

and when i look at the logs it says:

```
Retrying authentication
do_auth   :auth failure: [user:myuser]  [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=ldap] [reason=unknown]
```

What am i missing here? thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE:**

installed OpenLdap to do a search with the following command:

> ldapsearch -x -h ldaps://my.ldap.server:port -d8

for ldapsearch command to work i modified `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` file as follows:

```
tls_reqcert allow
TLS_CACERTDIR /home/myuser/cacertss
LDAPTLS_CACERT /home/myuser/cacertss
```

It returns all the entries but i still cant authenticate using

> testsaslauthd -u username -p password -f /var/run/saslauthd/mux

**what do i need to do here to get this authenticated?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 5 days of struggle found out that the settings i used was for `Active directory` where i should be using settings for `LDAP` as following:

```
ldap_servers: ldaps://test.ldap.server:1234
ldap_search_base: Ou=PeopleAuthSrch,DC=abc,DC=com
ldap_filters: (uid=%u)
ldap_tls_cacert_file: /path/to/my/certificate
```

I did install `cyrus-sasl-md5` as Bertold Kolics mentioned, i'm not sure if that played the part on authenticating the user.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the exercise of setting SASL setup with OpenLDAP and TLS on RedHat Linux 7.2 and I managed to get something similar working fine.

As I mentioned in my previous post, make sure that you have the `cyrus-sasl-md5` package installed.

I would first try to get everything working **without** SSL. Only after you have your setup working without SSL move to the SSL part.

- You need to make sure that `saslauthd` accepts the CA certificate of 
  the certificate used by the LDAP server. In particular,
  `ldap_tls_cacert_file` option in `/etc/saslauthd.conf` is your friend
- If you have SELinux enabled, make sure that `saslauthd` can access the certificate files. If you are unsure, tail the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file and look for entries with the "denied" keyword. I have found the `audit2allow` tool a great way to enable access that was previously denied. You can also just disable SELinux temporarily using the `setenforce Permissive` command

Comment: i installed `cyrus-sasl-md5` restarted `saslauthd` and made sure `ldap_tls_cacert_file` points to the certificate used by the `ldap`. I also looked into `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and i dont see anything denied. However i still have the same problem. Log inside `/var/log/messages/` doesn't say much beside what i mentioned above. Any idea?

Comment: Does this work without SSL? It if does, then it is an SSL issue. You may also try updating the CA certificates trusted on the system by default. Look for the command `update-ca-certs` and/or poke around in the `/etc/pki/ca-trust/` directories.